# Javascript Array get maximum value by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var myarr = new Array();
myarr[0] = {key: 'A', value:900};
myarr[1] = {key: 'B', value:190};
myarr[2] = {key: 'B', value:160};
myarr[3] = {key: 'A', value:10};
```

What I am expecting is to get the 'A's Maximum and 'B's Maximum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way;

```
var maxes = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++)
{
    var item = maxes[myarr[i].key];
    maxes[myarr[i].key] = isNaN(item) ? myarr[i].value : Math.max(item, myarr[i].value);
}

for (var key in maxes)
    alert(key + " max = " + maxes[key]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var maxNumbers = {};
var myarr = [
    {key: 'A', value:110},
    {key: 'B', value:190},
    {key: 'B', value:160},
    {key: 'B', value:890},
    {key: 'A', value:80}   
];

for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
    maxNumbers[myarr[i].key] = maxNumbers[myarr[i].key] || myarr[i].value;
    if (maxNumbers[myarr[i].key] < myarr[i].value) {
        maxNumbers[myarr[i].key] = myarr[i].value
    }
}
console.log(maxNumbers) //{ A: 110, B: 890 }
```

Answer (score 0):

there might be some frameworks like underscore with a solution, I'd just loop over the array once

```
var max = {}
  , current, i
for(i = 0; i < myarr.length;i++) {
  current = myarr[i];
  // initial value
  if(max[current.key] === undefined) {
    max[current.key] = current.value
  }
  // check if value is higher
  if(current.value > max[current.key]) {
    max[current.key] = current.value;
  }
}
console.log(max)
```

I haven't tested it, but it should give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce` (see [**MDN**](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Freduce&ei=cdCSVKuFI8f1OLz3gJgG&usg=AFQjCNHHMuqxJ882tP03jasOvA3-26VV9Q&sig2=y2tIf-OMD5CxQBfITR2s5Q&bvm=bv.82001339,d.ZWU))

```js
var myarr = [{key: 'A', value:900},
             {key: 'B', value:190},
             {key: 'B', value:160},
             {key: 'A', value:10}
            ];
var max = myarr.reduce( function(a, b) { return b.value > a ? b : a; });

document.querySelector('#result').textContent = 
     'object with max value in myarr =>; ' + 
      JSON.stringify(max) + ' (value: ' + max.value + ')';
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```